# how to display a popup window that focus on a particular division id?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

sample pages will be displayed "popup.html"

```
<html>
<div id="one"> </ div>
<div id="two"> </ div>
<div id="three"> </ div>
<div id="four"> </ div>
</ html>
```

Now I just want to display a popup that focus on div id = "three". What coding should I add to this script?

```
<input type = "button" value = "New Window!" onClick = "window.open ('popup.html', 'popupwindow', 'width = 400, height = 200')">
```

Then how to disable the maximize function in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the window feature dialog = yes or 1. The dialog feature removes all icons (restore, minimize, maximize) from the window's titlebar, leaving only the close button

```
window.open ('popup.html', 'popupwindow', 'width = 400, height = 200, dialog=yes')
```

You can find more info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

Another option you can consider is creating an iframe in the DOM on hovering over or focus of the div and loading the href as the iframe's src= attribute. In order to make it look like a popup, you would need to position the iframe at an absolute location, and set its z-index CSS property to a higher value than the rest of the page content.

Comment: thank your for the answer.. And if I just want to display a popup that focus on div id = "three". What coding should I add to this script? "window.open ('popup.html', 'popupwindow', 'width = 400, height = 200, dialog=yes')"

Comment: onfocus event may not work for div elements. You should change to a link (anchor) or use onclick with div. eg: <div id="three" onclick = "window.open ('http://google.com', 'popupwindow', 'width = 400, height = 200, dialog=yes')"> THREE </div>

Comment: Sorry Bad english.. I need a javascript function to display a specific div when i click the link/button, for example div id = "three". So if this div in the middle, the popup only displays middle part of the page.

Comment: For that you need to create an anchor with id in that page (<a id="three">Section Three</a>) and then point to it like this - popup.html#three. More info: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp